# How to use XQuery to fetch NULL values for INT

Tags: t-sql, xquery-sql

I have the following example

```
DECLARE @MyXml XML 

SET @MyXml = CONVERT(XML, '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
                            <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                                <number xsi:nil="true" />
                            </root>')

SELECT @MyXml.value('(/root/number)[1]', 'INT') AS MyNumber
```

The above listing gives me a **0** instead of a `NULL` that I would expect. I know I am using `Schema Instance`, but shouldn't it be a widely accepted standard already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text()`:

<kbd>**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376117)**</kbd>

```
DECLARE @MyXml XML 

SET @MyXml = CONVERT(XML, 
  '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <number xsi:nil="true" />
  </root>')

SELECT @MyXml.value('(/root/number/text())[1]', 'INT') AS MyNumber
```